# REST Uploading/downloading large file with Spring boot/JPA, Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bytea

I'm trying to upload ~700MB file and download the same through REST API in Spring boot with Postgres as database. I know Postgres is not the way to go but still, I'm trying to solve it as it is.

REST upload works after I added -Xmx2024m to VM while running.
REST download gives error while calling `uploadObjectEntityRepository.findById(id)`:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1381847031
```

Error would mean the data is corupt, but the upload service ended clean. There were no errors during upload in the Postgres log also. In the database, field `data` is of type `bytea`.

What could be the problem?

Abbreviated code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UploadObjectEntity")
public class UploadObjectEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
    private byte[] data;
    ...
}

@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<UploadObject> upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile file){
    ...
    UploadObject o = customService.saveUploadObject(file);
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getByteArray(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    UploadObject uploadObject = customService.load(id);
    ByteSource byteSource = ByteSource.wrap(uploadObject.getData());

    InputStream stream = byteSource.openStream();

    response.setContentType(...);
    response.setContentLength(...);
    IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
}

//Custom Service
public UploadObject saveUploadObject(MultipartFile file) {
    ...
    UploadObjectEntity uploadObjectEntity = new UploadObjectEntity();
    uploadObjectEntity.setData(file.getBytes());
    ...
    uploadObjectEntity = uploadObjectEntityRepository.save(uploadObjectEntity);

    return uploadObjectEntityMapper.toDto(uploadObjectEntity);
}

public UploadObject load(Long id) {
    return uploadObjectEntityRepository.findById(id).map(uploadObjectEntityMapper::toDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code **application.properties**

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1000MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB
```